# Collapsed jQuery UI Accordion within Wordpress

Tags: jquery, user-interface, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to achieve collapsed accordion on a page load, unless someone goes to a specific tab. I've got accordion working, but can't get it to collapse. I'm using Wordpress platform and my template displays output like this:

```
<div id="accordion" class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-accordion-icons" role="tablist">
            <section class="post-4 page type-page status-publish hentry clearfix">
                    <h1 class="entry-title acc-header dark-side ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-active ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-expanded="true" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><a href="#">Boon Villas – it is all about partnership</a></h1>
                    <div class="the-content dark-side ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" style="height: 368px; display: block; " role="tabpanel">
                    Some content 1
                    </div><!-- end #the-content-->
        </section>
                <section class="post-4 page type-page status-publish hentry clearfix">
            <h1 class="entry-title acc-header dark-side ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span><a href="#6" id="6">Our Commitment</a></h1>
            <div class="the-content dark-side ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" style="height: 368px; display: none; " role="tabpanel">
                Some content 2
            </div><!-- .the-content -->
    </section>

        <section class="post-4 page type-page status-publish hentry clearfix">
            <h1 class="entry-title acc-header dark-side ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span><a href="#10" id="10">Our People</a></h1>
            <div class="the-content dark-side ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" style="height: 368px; display: none; " role="tabpanel">

                Some content 3
            </div><!-- .the-content -->
    </section>

        <section class="post-4 page type-page status-publish hentry clearfix">
            <h1 class="entry-title acc-header dark-side ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span><a href="#17" id="17">Languages Spoken</a></h1>
            <div class="the-content dark-side ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" style="height: 368px; display: none; " role="tabpanel">

                Some content 4

            </div><!-- .the-content -->
    </section>

</div>
```

My jQuery is:

```
        var accOpt = {
            active: false,
            header: '.acc-header',
            navigation: true,
            event: 'mouseover',
            fillSpace: false,
            animated: 'easeslide',
            collapsible: true,
            allwayOpen: false
        };
    var accTab = <?php if ( !$_GET['id']) { echo 0;} else {echo $_GET['id'];} ?>;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#accordion').accordion( accOpt );
        $("#accordion").accordion( 'activate', accTab );
    });
```

I'm using the PHP to get the id parameter from link to decide which tab should be open. Question is how to achieve all tabs collapsed if there is no id or id=0 => first tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working after a second thought, here's the code:

```
        var tabID = <?php if ( !$_GET['id']) { echo 0;} else {echo $_GET['id'];} ?>; // set tabID to be open

    var accOpt = {
            active: false,
            header: '.acc-header',
            navigation: true,
            event: 'click',
            fillSpace: false,
            animated: 'easeslide',
            collapsible: true,
            allwayOpen: false
        };
    $('#accordion').accordion( accOpt );


    if ( tabID && tabID > 0 ) { //tabID is defined and tabID > 0 activate the tab

        $("#accordion").accordion( 'activate', tabID );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should cause all to be "collapsed" on Page Load.

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
      active: false
});
```

To allow people to close it again, set `collapsible: true`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I already have these options defined in accOpt variable, as you can see, and it does not load collapsed.

Comment: Take a look at the JsFiddle. Accordion disabled at start, then added on an Event. You could customize this for yourself to a onHover. http://jsfiddle.net/dane/4PrV3/54/

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't explain myself better. What I was trying to achieve is:
If visitor comes to the page with accordion it would be displayed collapsed, however if he clicks on a link to get to a specific tab it should open on the required tab. I've got it working now, but thanks for your time and effort.